# How to send notification upon completion of CloudFormation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

We have a CloudFormation stack that we want to provide to our clients.  When they run the stack, we want to receive some output values directly, i.e. we don't want them to need them to send us the output.  Our first thought was to use SNS and the notification capabilities of CF but it seems that the topic must be in the account running the template and can't be in another account.  We also considered subscribing to the existing SNS topic as part of the template but that doesn't get a message sent.

We realize that CF is a resource creation tool but we think there must be a way to get the info relayed to us automatically.  Doesn't have to be SNS.  Any ideas on how we might be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Update your CF script to contain a lambda and cloud watch rule which runs every 5 minutes on a cron.

Give the lambda IAM permissions to query the stack/get any output values you require.

When the lambda triggers you query the data you need and can send it to yourself however you see fit. E.g http POST to an API you own.

To finish up your lambda should call the cloud watch API to disable the cloud watch rule so this code doesn't run again.

You should consider if all this offsets the effort of saying to your client "please send us details of x y z". If you have 10 clients, probably not, if you have 1000 clients then possibly.